# Export registry from a nonbootable harddrive?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-registry, export

I was wondering if there was a way to export the entire registry from a nonbootable hard drive, and import it into a new computer's registry?

I know you can import hives one by one using regedit, but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to merge the entire registry from one computer into the registry of another? I can't say I've ever done this, or even know a guy who once met a guy who tried this but just thinking about it gives me an upset stomach.

That being said, [RegFileExport](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_file_offline_export.html) by NirSoft can dump offline hive files to standard .reg files which can then be concatenated and imported using RegEdit.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, hopefully this doesn't break the fresh install I have humming along ;)

Comment: Here be dragons. I'd be interested in hearing if this wild scheme works ;)

Comment: It worked (for the most part).  I lost admin privileges (should fix that), and iTunes utterly died, but everything else transferred over pretty well.

Comment: fyi, anyone who wants to try this instead of reinstalling everything, I only transferred over the SOFTWARE hive, and each user's hive (look at the registry wiki page for their locations).  Also, DO NOT CHANGE THE NAME OF ANY OF THE ACCOUNTS; your computer will die a horrible bsod.